# Make Swig Generate a Intermediary C# Struct and Not Intermediary Class

Tags: c#, c++, swig, directive

Currently in my C++ code I have a struct in my GeoCoordinate2d.h module:

```
namespace QuadKeys
{
    struct __declspec(dllexport) Latitude
    {
        double m_lat;
        ...
    };
}
```

When I invoke Swig with the `-csharp` flag on my `.swig` file.

```
%module SwigQuadKey
%{
    #include "QuadKey/QuadKey.h"
%}
...
%include "QuadKey/GeoCoordinate2d.h"
...
%rename(GeoCoordinate2d) QuadKeys::GeoCoordinate2d;
%include "QuadKey/QuadKey.h"
...
```

I get the following C# module, `Latitude.cs` which contains code of this form:

```
public class Latitude : global::System.IDisposable {
    private global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef swigCPtr;
    protected bool swigCMemOwn;

    public Latitude(double val) :       
        this(SwigQuadKeyPINVOKE.new_Latitude__SWIG_0(val), true) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to tell Swig to make the CSharp output to be of type `struct Latitude` and not `class Latitude`? If the answer is no, please refer to the doc where this is stated, or a valid reason why it is not possible.